# What game do these tiles belong to?

Tags: identify-this-game

Black letters with 20 in the bottom right corner. The backs are blank

[image]

Comment: What are they made of?  are they cheap plastic or something heavier?

Answer (score 7):

Not Scrabble, but [Dabble](https://www.dabblegame.com/boardgame.php) (publisher's site). Amazon has more photos, for example at their [Spanish](https://www.amazon.es/INI-Dabble-palabras-r%C3%A1pido-familia/dp/B01N2QN7J5) site. This game comes with English and Spanish tiles

I can't find images of the Spanish-specific tiles, but I'm confident because:

- the fonts match for both the letters and the number (for at least one version - the photos at Amazon show two different letter fonts)
- the tile values are plausible (Q is 30 in Dabble, for example)
- the [rules](https://www.dabblegame.com/dabble_rules_1_1.pdf) mention removing these 6 tiles for play in English - except there's no mention of a "ch" tile, leaving a little doubt.  Those Spanish tiles to be removed are described in lowercase, while the other tiles and indeed nearly all word games use uppercase.  The latest sales description [on their website](https://inillc.com/index.php/games/dabble/) now mentions 8 Spanish tiles, so it's safe to assume the the 2 extras are "ch".

The game was refreshed in 2017 (when this font started to be used), but the rules date back to the 2011 initial release (as they show a typewriter-style font).

Comment: I don't think your amazon link will work for people not in the UK

Comment: @JoeW It should. I've been looking at [Spanish Amazon](https://www.amazon.es/INI-Dabble-palabras-r%C3%A1pido-familia/dp/B01N2QN7J5) quite a bit just now, and .com.

Comment: The .co.uk link doesn't work (Netherlands user here); the .es one does.

Comment: @Glorfindel strange.  I'll rearrange the links as I obviously can't test to figure out why Amazon are doing such strange things

Comment: I got a page not found error on the .co.uk link but the .es link works just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @JoeW - no idea why but it's fixed now

Comment: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/105602/dabble has under the community section the value of the spanish tiles which are matching

Comment: Thanks @Zibelas - but still no "ch", though I note that "ch" is included in Scrabble. Also that Spanish orthography has changed what  counts as a letter more than once, with the history suggesting that "ch" has more reasons to be included the "rr".

Comment: The official website https://inillc.com/index.php/games/dabble/ mentions that the spanish version has 8 extra tiles which would match as well

Comment: https://boardgamegeek.com/image/2554839/dabble shows most of these letters, but is also missing the "ch"